# Find keys from both the Linked HashMap and store it in a list alternatively

Tags: java, collections

you have two LinkedHashMaps

```
Map m1 = new LinkedHashMap();
m1.put("1","One");
m1.put("3","Three");
Map m2 = new LinkedHashMap();
m2.put("2","Two");
m2.put("4","Four");
```

Find keys from both the Linked HashMap and store it in a list alternatively.

The list should contain 1,2,3,4.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: really sound homework ! what you tried so far?

Comment: you have two LinkedHashMaps........                                                                    Map m1=new LinkedHashMap();
m1.put("1","One");
m1.put("3","Three");

Map m2=new LinkedHashMap();
m2.put("2","Two");
m2.put("4","Four");

Find keys from both the Linked HashMap and store it in a list alternatively..                                                      The list should contain 1,2,3,4.

Comment: This has *got* to be homework... come on, 'fess up and add the `homework` tag!

Comment: you don't mean alternatively but alternating, am I right ?

Comment: @abhayhappy2 - In future, you will get a better response (and less down votes) if you show you have put some effort into solving the problem yourself. Also, when someone asks you "what have you tried so far", it serves no purpose to just repeat the requirements. Please post your code next time. It does not have to be perfect. But posting it will demonstrate that you are not just asking someone else to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

```
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.addAll(m1.keySet());
        list.addAll(m2.keySet());
        Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Works in this example, but I think he wants them to interleave.

Answer (score 2):

Really sounds like homework, so I won't give you the exact code. I think the answers so far are wrong, as they don't interleave. Try this:

Get an Iterator iterator1 for the first map.
Get an Iterator iterator2 for the second map.

Use a while loop and ask for the next element in iterator1 and iterator2. The rest is for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and add both keySets from your maps, like so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map m1 = new LinkedHashMap();
        m1.put("1","One");
        m1.put("3","Three");
        Map m2 = new LinkedHashMap();
        m2.put("2","Two");
        m2.put("4","Four");
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.addAll(m1.keySet());
        list.addAll(m2.keySet());
        for(String s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This would produce 1,3,2,4 instead of 1,2,3,4.

Comment: After that u can sort and print....                       Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println("--------------");
System.out.println(list);

Comment: I quote the OP: "The list should contain 1,2,3,4."; so, my list, does it contain 1,2,3 and 4 ? I would say yes.

Comment: It definitely contains each of those elements, but not in the order proposed by OP. I guess OP should be clearer about what he wants, I thought that by alternatively he meant that they should alternate, i.e. interleave. @abhayhappy2, what should be a result if you have 1, 2 as keys in the first hashmap and a, b in the second? 1,a,2,b, or 1,2,a,b?